# Problems trying to rotate my ship to be parallel to the mesh normal its floating on

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, mesh, normals

So I'm making a game where you sail in a pirate ship, I animated a sea in blender and made a script to update the mesh collider so raycasts trigger properly on the animated mesh, so far so good.

now the problem I'm facing is with the boat, so far I have been able to make the boat ride the waves:

```
// This is the script that handles the riding of the waves.

[SerializeField] private LayerMask m_whatIsSea;
[SerializeField] private float m_offsetFromWaterSurface;

private void Update()
{
    // Shoot a raycast from above the water down to detect the height.
    RaycastHit _hit;
    if (Physics.Raycast(gameObject.transform.position + (Vector3.up * (Mathf.Abs(m_offsetFromWaterSurface * 4))), -Vector3.up, out _hit, m_whatIsSea))
    {
        Float(_hit);
    }
}

private void Float(RaycastHit hit)
{
    // Than move the boat to the height.
    Vector3 _newPosition = new Vector3(gameObject.transform.position.x, hit.point.y + m_offsetFromWaterSurface, gameObject.transform.position.z);
    transform.position = _newPosition;
}
```

But when I move the ship with a ship controller, it does correctly change its height.
but all attempts at making my ship rotate according to the raycasted mesh normal (the hit.normal in the above code) haven't worked out for me.

I have made attempts that did somewhat work out for me, but the biggest issue in those is that the mesh consisting of big triangles doesn't give me a smooth rotation rather constantly snapping to the normals, which of course isn't good.

[image: Picture of the wave mesh:]

So the final result I'm trying to achieve is that my ship rotates so that it's visually going up and down the waves instead of having the front clipping through.

I appreciate any help! I've been trying to come up with a solution for longer than I can admit. :-)

Comment: In your code I don't see any attempt .. could you show what you tried?

Answer (score 0):

I would try [Vector3.RotateTowards](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.RotateTowards.html).

The 4th argument `maxRadiansDelta` in the method `public static Vector3 RotateTowards(Vector3 current, Vector3 target, float maxRadiansDelta, float maxMagnitudeDelta);` should allow you to rotate the ship in the hit triangle normal's direction with `maxRadiansDelta` as a maximum value you can play with to set and make the rotation smooth enough.